# VTK installation in windows 8.1

Tags: visual-studio-2013, vtk

I'm new to VTK and I tried to install VTK 6.2.0 and cMake 3.3.2. I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 and my OS is windows 8.1.

I have followed the installation guidelines given in [here](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Building/Windows) and I have successfully complete steps up to step 5. But to do step 6 I can't find a release folder in my bin (C:\MyProjects\VTK-bin\bin) it contain only a debug folder.

I can't find where I have made the mistake. What can I do to overcome this problem?

Comment: see how to compile in debug/release mode in visual studio   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wx0123s5.aspx

Answer (score 1):

It is in the visual studio IDE that you select Debug or Release or some other configuration. There should be a drop down menu in the top toolbar. 
It has nothing to do with VTK, almost nothing to do with cmake (although you can restrict config types during config step) and almost everything to do with Visual Studio.
HTH,
Miro